# В телеграм боте на джава подчеркивает chat_id и выдает как ошибку

Tags: java, telegram-bot

```
  @Override
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) { //реакция на изменения
    Message msg = update.getMessage();
    Long chat_id = msg.getChatId();

    if (msg!=null && msg.hasText()){
        try{
            execute(new SendMessage(chat_id, "Hi " + msg.getText()));
        }
        catch(TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

в итоге подчеркивает chat_id и выдает как ошибку

Comment: getChatId() - какой тип возвращает?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте текст ошибки в вопрос. Отредактировать вопрос можно, нажав на кнопку «[править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1435811/edit)» под вопросом.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо этого:

```
Long chat_id = msg.getChatId();
```

Попробуйте:

```
String chat_id = msg.getChatId().toString();
```